# Camera 2 API with SurfaceView, stretching preview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I can't understand why my preview always stretches when I set up it on one Android device in broke on other... const CameraAspectRatio is 0.75.

How can I calculate aspect ratio? How can I setup non-stretched preview on different devices?

```
protected override void OnLayout(bool _, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
    var screenWidth = r - l;
    var screenHeight = b - t;

    var msw = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(screenWidth, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
    var msh = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(screenHeight, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);

    _surfaceView.Measure(msw, msh);

    var finalHeight = screenWidth / CameraAspectRatio;
    var qq = screenHeight - finalHeight;
    var verticalOffset = (int)(qq / 2);
    _surfaceView.Layout(l, t + verticalOffset, r, b - verticalOffset);
}
```

[STRETCH PREVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcHp5.jpg)

[Also using viewgroup + ISurfaceHolderCallback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgqpB.png)